# <Alt> Key Macros in vim-latex

Tags: vim-latex

`<Alt-L>`,`<Alt-B>`,`<Alt-C>` and `<Alt-I>` are four default alt key macros in vim latex-suite. However, I cannot used it in my mac. It only types `¬` `∫` `ç` `ˆ` respectively. May I know how to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried using cmd instead of alt? I'm not that familiar with vim, but often in the mac systems, alt gets substituted by cmd.

Comment: @ilFuria I tried `cmd` but get `<D-i>` or other strange results.

Comment: Sorry, then @Joe. It was worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that just adding `set macmeta` in `.vimrc` will work. It enables the mapping of meta key (alt/option) in macvim.